# how to pass android data from ajax through php and then to mysql

Tags: php, android, ajax

need to pass data to android app through ajax by using php.
the data is pulled from mysql database through a select query

please provide me code example how to perform the task
i had search the internet and i find the below code for reference
http://www.grobmeier.de/android-does-not-fire-ajax-reqests-because-they-are-caches-ajax-requests-at-least-on-jquery-mobile-10072011.html#.UGvLbU3A-RI

how to perform the select query to fetch the data array.
please correct me if the example is not proper.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "yoururl.html",
       context: document.body,
       cache : false,
       data: { 
            username :  $('#username').val(), 
            password :  $('#password').val(), 
       },
       success: function ( data ) {
           // do something
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regular HTTP request (made from AJAX, of course): you send variables to the server by the method you choose. Something like: `http://www.example.com/script.php?var1=foo&var2=bar` Those variables can be accessed within script.php this way:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['var1'], PHP_EOL; // shows foo
echo $_GET['var2'], PHP_EOL; // shows bar

?>
```

If you use POST method instead of GET you must use `$_POST[<whatever>]` to access you variables.

Once you got the values within PHP you can execute the query you need to persist that data.

There is a ton of this arround Internet, if you make a minimal search you will find exactly what you want.